# Bounds on flux integrals

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

What are some handy upper bounds for surface integrals (and their proofs)? Specifically, suppose $f$ is a bounded function on a surface $S$. Do we have
$$ \int_{\partial S} F \cdot n \; \mathrm{d}S \leq m(\partial S) \sup_{x \in \partial S} F,$$
where $m(\,\cdot\,)$ is the Lebesgue measure? Cauchy Schwarz seems applicable.

Comment: I believe you've got a notation problem: the integral is on $S$, not $\partial S$. You probably confused this with $S$ sometimes being the boundary of a 3d solid body.

Comment: Aren't flux integrals taken over the boundary of the manifold?

Comment: No, flux integrals are taken over any surface. If, in particular, $S = \partial V$, with $V$ being a 3d solid body, then it's even nicer, because you could use Gauss's theorem. If you *really* want to speak about $\partial S$, then the integral over it is a line integral, which means that the measure on $\partial S$ cannot be $\Bbb d S$ (which is the measure on $S$).

Comment: An important remark: you can't use the Lebesgue measure on $\partial S$, because $\partial S$ has codimension $1$, and thus Lebesgue measure $0$ (where by Lebesgue measure I understand the measure on the ambient space).

Comment: Oh right absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $S$ has finite measure and using the fact that, under very general conditions, $| \int _X f | \le \int _X |f| \le \sup |f| \ m (X)$, and assuming also that $n$ is a vector of length $ \| n \| _{\Bbb R^3} = 1$, we have that

$$\left |\int _S F \cdot n \ \Bbb d S \right| \le \int _S |F \cdot n| \ \Bbb d S \le \int _S \| F \| _{\Bbb R^3} \| n \| _{\Bbb R^3} \ \Bbb d S = \int _S \| F \| _{\Bbb R^3} \ \Bbb d S \le \sup _{s \in S} \|F (s)\| _{\Bbb R^3} \ m_S(S) .$$

Alternatively, one may use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality in $L^2 (S, \Bbb R^3, \Bbb d S)$ (the space of vector-valued functions on $S$, of square-integrable norm) and write

$$\left |\int _S F \cdot n \ \Bbb d S \right| = | \langle F, n \rangle _{L^2} | \le \|F\| _{L^2} \|n\| _{L^2} = \sqrt {\int _S \|F\| _{\Bbb R^3} ^2 \ \Bbb d S} \sqrt {\int _S \|n\| _{\Bbb R^3} ^2 \ \Bbb d S} = \sqrt {\int _S \|F\| _{\Bbb R^3} ^2 \ \Bbb d S} \sqrt {m_S(S)} .$$

In the above, $m_S$ is the measure induced by the volume form of $S$, *not* the restriction of the ambient Lebesgue measure to $S$ (this one would be $0$, since $S$ has codimension $1$, so it is "too thin").